Semi-definiteness of symmetric matrix with some zero diagonal elements
Let we have a symmetric matrix
$$
 A=A^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$such that some of its diagonal elements are zero.
Is it true that $A$ is semidefinite only if it is diagonal?

No, for example
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
has some zero diagonal elements, is symmetric and semidefinite but not diagonal.
It is semidefinite because its associated quadratic form is
$$\begin{pmatrix}x & y & z\end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = y(y + z) + z(y + z) = (y + z)^2 \geq 0$$

Thanks a lot! May I clarify: should row and column which intersects by zero element always be zero?

@mm12 Yes. E.g. suppose $a_{11}=0$ but $a_{12}\ne0$. Let $x=(t,1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Since $A$ is positive semidefinite, we have $0\le x^TAx=2a_{12}t+a_{22}$ for any positive or negative real number $t$. Hence $a_{12}$ must be zero.
